# how to record songs when it is playing in iphone by xcode?

Tags: iphone

I've a problem i want to play a song and simultaneously record that song.I'm using AVRecorder to record the file. Actually small sound clipping which is in my project can be record and play fine. But if i play anf song from itunes then it gives some problem. Please someone help me with accurate code. Thanx

Comment: First, be more specific. "has some problem" will not get you any help at all.  Second, Apple probably made this impossible to do so you cannot duplicate copyrighted content.

Comment: thanx a lot I just want to know whether it is possible or not.

Comment: You should know that was merely a guess.  I dont know that for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanx everyone, I got answer of my question. I'm using Direc2 sample code for this and its working very fine.